# Watch a Directory and Process Copied Files -Check for Copy Completion and Open Handles

Tags: c#, .net, file, directory, filesystemwatcher

I need to watch a directory for image files(jpeg,png,tif,gif,bmp) and process new files placed there.Im trying to implement this using FileSystemWatcher

```
private void watch()
{
  FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
  watcher.Path = path;
  watcher.Filter = "*.*";
  watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
  watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

But how can i make sure that the file is copied in full and there is no handle locking the file before trying to open it?

Answer (score 1):

To process a file once its fully copied you need to add the below filter:

```
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
```

This will notify once the file is fully copied into the directory

Ref : [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

For multi file filter you have two options:

```
watcher.Filter = "*.*";
```

or use the following constructor:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("path","*.*");
```

Comment: Thanks..but how do i add multiple file filters

Comment: That can't handle partial file copies if the copying process fails while copying the file, such as an FTP connection dropping in the middle of sending the file.

Comment: yes but that is not the headache of the application watching the directory..for that you might have to implement some sort of messaging between the copier and the directory watcher

Answer (score 0):

The only process that knows whether or not the file is fully copied is the one doing the copying.  Think about it - a file is merely a stream of data.  Without additional information, there's no way to know how much data is supposed to be in the file.

Without some form of communication that the file is fully copied, the only thing any other process can do is guess based upon the the file not being open and not being written to any more, and then hope the guess is correct.  Anything like this that relies on the file no longer being written to nor held open by any other process can not handle failures.  If a file is being copied by a process such as FTP and the network connection drops in the middle of copying a file for any reason, a "guess-and-hope" process will incorrectly identify the file as complete.

There are several methods to solve this problem, but they all require the sending process to send a signal of some type to the receiver that the file is done.

You can have the sending process send a "DONE" file - after sending `DataFile`, the sending process then sends a zero-length file called `DataFile.done`.  Once you see `DataFile.done`, you know for certain that `DataFile` has been fully copied.  If you don't see `DataFile.done`, `DataFile` isn't fully copied.

You can also have the sending process rename the file - if your underlying OS and file system support atomic file rename operations.  You can have your sending process initially send `DataFile.copying`, and when the copying is complete rename the file to `DataFile`.  Any file that has a `.copying` extension is still in the process of being copied.

Some data file formats also indicate complete files.  PDF files follow a specified format and you can tell if they're complete.  XML files can be constructed in a way that you can tell if they're complete.  But this is not an efficient solution as it requires parsing the contents of the file, and if the files are large or there are performance requirements the continual reading of each file multiple times can result in serious IO performance problems.

Again, you can't solve this problem without the sending process sending some sort of DONE flag.  The receiving process simply doesn't have enough data to do anything other than guess when the file is done, and then it can only hope it's made the correct guess.

Systems that rely on guessing and hoping generally aren't very reliable.

Comment: Thanks.Im just trying to monitor normal copy operation by Windows Explorer.If Filesystem Watcher cannot detect new file creation,then what is the point of this event -FileSystemWatcher.Created?

Comment: @techno The problem isn't if it detects it - the problem is it can't tell when the file copy fails in the middle.  If that's not a concern, it can work OK for you.

Comment: Its not a concern.The thing is if the copy operation goes well(without errors) i just dont want the file to be read before its written fully.

Comment: @techno *i just dont want the file to be read before its written fully*  You're seeing how *hard* it actually is to solve this problem while accounting for both completeness and error conditions. Without cooperation from the sender, the only things you can do are to make sure the file isn't held open by another process. If it's not open, as long as it's not on file system shared with other hosts, no one can be writing to it - you hope, as you can miss a process that closes the file between writes. Then you can wait until it's been, say, 60 sec or so since the last write.

Comment: And then, once you get that working to your satisfaction, you have to figure out how to keep *track* of the files you've seen or processed and the files you're waiting to be completed.  And how to handle any files copied to the directory during any time when your watcher process isn't running.

Comment: I have already solved this.The created event only fires when a new file is created,so there is no need to keep track of the files.I only need to watch the directory when the watch function in my program is called.

Comment: Well,yes there were issues like 'Out of Memory Exception' etc .. managed to get over it by using a timer.